# Add several scatter glyphs to one plot (figure) - Python, Bokeh

Tags: plot, bokeh, figure, scatter, glyph

I am trying to plot several scatter glyphs to one figure, using a loop. The goal is to use an own glyph for each brand and to update the values if another value is chosen by the Select widgets.

But the figure shows an empty graph. I assume that the problem is the ColumnDataSource and the update in the function "update()".
This is an executable example. Do you have any idea?

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

import pandas as pd

brands = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
product = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7']
price = [2, 3, 54, 48, 9, 2, 4]
size = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
value = [5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 0, 1]
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
col = ['ID', 'brand', 'product', 'price', 'size', 'value']
label = ['price', 'size', 'value']

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(brands, product, price, size, value, id), columns=col)

# Widgets:
select_x_axis = Select(title="x-Axis:", value=label[0], options=label)
select_y_axis = Select(title="y-Axis:", value=label[1], options=label)

# Set up figure
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("index", "@id"),
    ('Brand', '@brand'),
    ('Product', '@product'),
    (select_x_axis.value, '@x'),
    (select_y_axis.value, '@y')
])

# Set up plots:
fig = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=800, title="xyz",
             # tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
             tools=[hover, 'reset'],
             x_axis_label=select_x_axis.value,
             y_axis_label=select_y_axis.value)
source = {}
plots = {}
for brand in brands:
    # Create Column Data Source that will be used by the plot
    source[brand] = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], id=[], product=[], brand=[]))
    plots[brand] = fig.scatter(x='x', y='y', size=5, source=source[brand])


def update():
    x_name = select_x_axis.value
    y_name = select_y_axis.value
    fig.xaxis.axis_label = x_name
    fig.yaxis.axis_label = y_name
    for brand in brands:
        df1 = df.loc[df['brand'] == brand]
        source[brand].data = dict(
            x=df1[x_name],
            y=df1[y_name],
            id=df1['ID'],
            product=df1['product'],
            brand=df1['brand']
        )

# Set up layouts and add to document
controls = [select_x_axis, select_y_axis]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

inputs = column(select_x_axis, select_y_axis)
update()  # initial load of the data

show(row(inputs, fig, width=1000))
#curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, fig, width=1000))
#curdoc().title = "xyz"
```

[resultig plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmWV5.png)

Comment: `show` generates *standalone HTML output*, i.e. there is no connection to any Python process. Real Python callbacks with `.on_change` will *never* be able to function in this mode. One way or another, a Bokeh server must be used in order to have real Python callbacks (The Bokeh server *is the Python process* that would execute your Python callback code).

Comment: Yes, I am using a bokey Server in my example. I just added this code here, for a quick executable snippet. So the problem is to set up a scatter plot for each brand, using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

import pandas as pd

def make_data() :
    brands = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
    product = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7']
    price = [2, 3, 54, 48, 9, 2, 4]
    size = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
    value = [5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 0, 1]
    ident = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    col = ['ID', 'brand', 'product', 'price', 'size', 'value']
    label = ['price', 'size', 'value']
    return pd.DataFrame(zip(brands, product, price, size, value, ident), columns=col)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    df = make_data()

    default_xcol = "price"
    default_ycol = "size"

    df["xvalues"] = df[default_xcol]
    df["yvalues"] = df[default_ycol]

    # Scatter plot
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[(name, "@" + name) for name in df.columns])
    figure = figure(tools=[hover, 'reset'])

    # Source    
    source = ColumnDataSource(df)
    figure.scatter("xvalues", "yvalues", source=source)

    # Selects 
    options = ["product", "price", "size", "value"]
    select_x_axis = Select(title="x-Axis:", value=default_xcol, options=options)
    select_y_axis = Select(title="y-Axis:", value=default_ycol, options=options)

    # callback
    callback = CustomJS(args={"source":source, "axis":figure.xaxis[0]}, code="""
        source.data['xvalues'] = source.data[cb_obj.value];
        source.change.emit();
        axis.axis_label = cb_obj.value;
        """)

    select_x_axis.js_on_change("value", callback)

    callback = CustomJS(args={"source":source, "axis":figure.yaxis[0]}, code="""
        source.data['yvalues'] = source.data[cb_obj.value];
        source.change.emit();
        axis.axis_label = cb_obj.value;
        """)   

    select_y_axis.js_on_change("value", callback)

    show(row(
        column(select_x_axis, select_y_axis), 
        figure, width=1000))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. In my code I am using a bokey server, thats why I used .on_change. I just added the "show" method to provide an executable code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. In my code I am using a bokey server, thats why I used .on_change. I just added the "show" method to provide an executable code.

So here your code does not exactly what I need. What I want is an extra scatter plot for each brand in one figure. The goal is to ge different colors and markers per brand and later on to "hide" the scatter plot by clicking on the brand name in the legend (interactive legend). 
Do you have any idea how to solve that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Interactive legend: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html?highlight=legend
Several plot is one figure: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/legend.html?highlight=legend

Answer (score 0):

@jsgounot Thanks for your help. I figured something out that works quiet well at the moment:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import d3

import pandas as pd

brands = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
product = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7']
price = [2, 3, 54, 48, 9, 2, 4]
size = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
value = [5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 0, 1]
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
col = ['ID', 'brand', 'product', 'price', 'size', 'value']
label = ['price', 'size', 'value']

colors = d3["Category20c"][len(brands)]
markers = ['circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'asterisk', 'circle_x', 'square_x', 'inverted_triangle', 'x', 'circle_cross', 'square_cross', 'diamond', 'cross']

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(id, brands, product, price, size, value), columns=col)

default_xcol = "price"
default_ycol = "size"

df["xvalues"] = df[default_xcol]
df["yvalues"] = df[default_ycol]

# Widgets:
select_x_axis = Select(title="x-Axis:", value=label[0], options=label)
select_y_axis = Select(title="y-Axis:", value=label[1], options=label)

# Set up figure
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("index", "@ID"),
    ('Brand', '@brand'),
    ('Product', '@product'),
    (select_x_axis.value, '@xvalues'),
    (select_y_axis.value, '@yvalues')
])

# Set up plots:
fig = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=800, title="xyz",
             # tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
             tools=[hover, 'reset'],
             x_axis_label=select_x_axis.value,
             y_axis_label=select_y_axis.value)

df_brand = []
sources = []
plots = {}
for index, brand in enumerate(df.brand.unique()):
    df_brand.append(df.loc[df['brand'] == brand])
    sources.append(ColumnDataSource(df_brand[index]))
    plots[brand] = fig.scatter(x='xvalues', y='yvalues', source=sources[index],
                               legend_label=brand,
                               marker=markers[index],
                               color=colors[index])
fig.legend.click_policy="hide"

callback_x = CustomJS(args={'sources': sources, 'axis': fig.xaxis[0], 'brands': df.brand.unique()}, code="""
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        var source = sources[i]
        source.data['xvalues'] = source.data[cb_obj.value];
        source.change.emit();
    }
    axis.axis_label = cb_obj.value;
    """)
callback_y = CustomJS(args={'sources': sources, 'axis': fig.yaxis[0], 'hov': fig.hover, 'brands': df.brand.unique()}, code="""
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        var source = sources[i]
        source.data['yvalues'] = source.data[cb_obj.value];
        source.change.emit();
    }
    axis.axis_label = cb_obj.value;
    """)


select_x_axis.js_on_change('value', callback_x)
select_y_axis.js_on_change('value', callback_y)

show(row(
        column(select_x_axis, select_y_axis),
        fig, width=1000))
```